# Pop up Related Issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

There is a button in my webpage which calls another page through AJAX.The page carries certain  data named "Match" if the query is successfully ran. Now I want that if a Match is recieved from the other page then a pop up  comes. Here's my code

```
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
<div class="overlay-content">
<h>ksadjaskjdaskdjaskdjaskdjaskdjaskdjasdk</h>  </div>
</div>
<button class="abc" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" >&#9776; Accept</button>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var a="Match";

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".abc").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'accept.php?w1=<?php echo $id ?>',
            success: function(data) {

               // $("p").text(data);
             if(a=data)
             {
               function openNav()
                {
                  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
                }
             }
             else
             {
               location.reload();         
             }
          }              

        });
      });
     });


  function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
   }
```

Comment: Are you facing issue with the popUp or the data?

Comment: I dont see any popup in your code. you can use bootstrap modal or if you can do with alert, then you dont need one. And exactly what will the popup do?